# Maximum angle that a wheeled body can climb at

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I've only recently been introduced to the concept of static vs dynamic friction and I was looking to check my understanding by determining the max angle a wheeled body can climb. In the diagram below the car is moving up the hill.

[image]

So by resolving parallel to the hill, the max angle a car could climb at a constant velocity is when
$$
N \mu_{s} = N\mu_{k} + mg\sin\theta
$$
Because $ N = mg\cos\theta $ , the equation can be re-arranged to give
$$
\tan\theta = \mu_{s} - \mu_{k}
$$

So is the tan of the max angle simply the difference between the two coefficients? This confused me because a car is capable of climbing a much steeper hill than a train however the difference between rubber and asphalt coefficients is not much greater than the difference between steel on steel and would only give a angle difference of 1 or 2 degrees, so I am wondering if I have made a mistake or a wrong assumption?

Comment: What's $\mu_k$? There's normally no $N \mu_k$ force in a scenario like this for a car (or it is negligible). A train, on the other hand, probably lacks the power/engine torque, to climb steep hills. Also, remember, that friction is distributed somewhat evenly between all wheels, but only some are driving the vehicle. In the case of a train, just the locomotive is powered.

Comment: I am confused why $ N \mu_{k} $ is negligible as according to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Physics_Study_Guide/Frictional_coefficients the coefficient of kinetic friction on asphalt on rubber is 0.67, surely that is too large to be made negligible?

Comment: @oneonefour i don't think a wheeled vehicle can climb up a hill without any engine force, what is $N_{\mu (s)}$ if it is force of static friction then your equations are wrong

Comment: @DeNiSkA , yeah I was a bit confused on the difference between the engine force and the traction force, are they not the same thing?

Comment: @OneOneFour by engine force i mean any force which is making the vehicle go up. And traction force and engine force are not the same.

Comment: @OneOneFour Looked it up. There should be no kinetic friction involved, the wheel is not skidding, neither is the car blocking its wheels and sliding forwards.

Comment: @DeNiSkA The only force that is making the vehicle go up is the force of friction between the wheels and the ground. There is no "propelling" force, as if a rocket would be strapped to the back of the car.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP i agree that friction is making car go up but i think the frictional force ($N_{\mu (k)}$ ) should not act backwards(*there is no other force acting backwards other than gravity and air resistance*) . (*assuming no slipping*)

Comment: @DeNiSkA That was what I meant with my very first comment. There is, of course, no backwards component to friction. I first though, maybe this is resistance to rolling, but as this is kinetic friction, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: just now i read that! i hope @OneOneFour is clear now

Comment: so if there is no coefficent of kinetic friction in this example then the angle a vehicle can climb is the arctan of the coefficent of static friction only?

Comment: I understand now why I was wrong with the kinetic friction thank you!

Comment: @OneOneFour yes, unless it starts slipping and reverts to the lower kinetic friction, going downhill in a slide from which it cannot recover :) the morale is to be careful when climbing steep hills

Answer (score 0):

At just under 38 degrees the static equation shows that the force down the slope (mgsin) is equal to the resistance due to friction (mu mgcos), ie the vehicle starts to lose grip.  Even if does have an engine this makes it difficult.

Comment: The maximum angle will depend on the coefficient of static friction between the wheels and the road. I don't see any numbers in the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the tires are well inflated and the car is moving uphill at a low constant speed, then the only significant friction is the static friction force from the road which is pushing the car up the hill (as a result of the engine turning the wheels). Then the maximum angle occurs when: $μ_S$N – (mg)sin(θ) = 0  and: N - (mg)cos(θ) = 0 (Assuming weight is evenly distributed on four driven wheels.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is about the grip required to move up a hill, and that the car's engine has sufficient power and torque to do the job.

The car will not be able to progress up a hill if it is so steep that the force of gravity puling the car down the direction of the slope is greater than the frictional force that prevents the car from sliding.

The gravitational force is simply Wsin, where W is the weight of the car. The simplest model is to take the frictional force to be Wcos, in which case the two forces become just equal to each other in magnitude when tan = .

That is a simplified explanation, since it assumes, amongst other things, that the weight of the car is evenly distributed over the driving wheels. That might hold roughly for a four wheel drive vehicle, but would not for a two wheel drive.

Comment: Actually, the weight distribution would depend on the location of the center of mass, and the angle of the hill.

Comment: Good point! Front wheel drive would not fare so well.

Answer (score -1):

The steepest angle a vehicle can climb is arctan(mu)

Or, tan^-1(coefficient of friction between tire and surface)

COF = 1,   Angle = 45°

COF = .7.  Angle = 35°

COF = .5.  Angle = 26°

COF = .25. Angle = 14°

COF = 0.   Angle = 0°

For adhesion:

COA = 2.   Angle = 63°

COA = 4.   Angle = 76°.  Oops, flips over backwards if GC is 18” above wheel patch line.